# VC dimension of intersection of half-spaces

Tags: cg.comp-geom, machine-learning, lg.learning, vc-dimension, high-dimensional-geometry

Define $$l_i(x) := \text{sgn} \left( w_i^\top x - b_i \right)$$

for $i=1,...,n$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$.

Then define the classifier

$$ g(x) := \max \{ l_1(x),..., l_n(x) \}$$

which represents the intersection of $n$ linear functions and hence a convex polytope in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with $n$ facets.

What is the VC dimension of the family of all $g$ of this form?

I found that an upper bound is $2 (d+1) n \text{log}_2( (d+1)n ).$

Comment: VC dimension is normally defined for _range spaces_ — pairs $(X, R)$ where $X$ is a set of points and $R\subseteq 2^X$ is a set of subsets of $X$ called _ranges_.  (Range spaces are also called set systems.)  I assume you want $X$ to be a convex polyhedron, but what are your ranges?  Or is $X=\mathbb{R}^n$ and $R$ the set of convex polyhedra?

Comment: I mean that $X$ is a convex polyhedron in dimension $n$ formed by the intersection of $n$ half-spaces.

Comment: And what is $R$?

Comment: on the off chance that you got confused and meant to say that $X$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $R$ is all translates of a convex polytope, does this answer your question: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.5223v2.pdf (the VC-dimension is infinite in $n=3$ and at most $3$ in $n=2$)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Let me reformulate the question.

Comment: I have found in [Haussler, Welzl - Epsilon nets and simplex range queries] that for a polytope of dimension $d$ with $n$ facets, the VC dimension is upper bounded by $2 (d+1) n \text{log}_2( (d+1)n )$. I do not know if a better bound is known.

Comment: so you actually mean the range space of all convex polytopes, taken as subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. you should understand that the VC dimension of "a polytope" is 0, because it's a single set! you need some family of sets here.

Comment: Thanks again. I meant the VC dimension of $g$. I am brand new to the concept of VC dimension.

Comment: Well, $d*n$ is an easy lower bound. I suspect this is the correct bound, but proving it is going to be not easy.

Answer (score 3):

It has been recently shown by Csikos, Kupavskii, Mustafa
in "Optimal Bounds on the VC-dimension" that the VC dimension of $k$-fold unions (or intersections or XORs) of half-spaces in $R^d$ behaves as
$$ \Theta(dk\log k),$$
https://jmlr.org/papers/v20/18-719.html

Additionally, in a recent tour de force, Kupavskii has given a polynomial bound on the VC-dimension of $k$-vertex polytopes:
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00493-020-4475-4

Comment: The upper bound for the intersection of halfspaces is well known and predates the work by Mustafa etal.

Comment: Indeed. It's the lower bound that was non-trivial. And the k-vertex polytope question was open for 30 years.