# Fat Shattering / VC dimension / Statistical Complexity of piecewise linear functions

Tags: machine-learning, lg.learning, vc-dimension, pac-learning

I am trying to establish a bound on the VC dimension of piecewise linear continuous functions with $k$ pieces. I am aware of an [earlier question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17477/vc-dimension-of-intersection-of-half-spaces) which tackles this problem in the case of *convex* piecewise linear functions. However, the fundamental argument seems to rely on the fact that the concept class induced by a convex piecewise linear function is given by the intersection of the concepts induced by its component hyperplanes - this doesn't apply in the general case.

When the $k$ breakpoints are fixed in place it seems obvious that the VC dimension would be $(k+1)(d+1)$. However, when the breakpoints are free to vary I am not sure how to establish a bound.

EDIT: I thought I would express why I am interested in such a result. I am studying the following learning setting, known as a Stackelberg prediction game.

As is standard, data is sampled from some underlying distribution $\mathcal{D}$. However, instead of sampling from the distribution directly the learner receives samples from an intermediary agent. Additionally each input example sampled comes with two labels $y$ and $z$.The label $y$ represents what the learner would like to predict, whilst the label $z$ represents what prediction the intermediary prefers.

At test time, the intermediary may modify input examples, with full knowledge of the predictor chosen by the learner, with the aim of getting a better prediction. More formally, instead of submitting an input example $\mathbf{x}$, the agent submits $\mathbf{x}^{\star}$:

$$
\mathbf{x}^{\star} \in \arg\min_{\tilde{\mathbf{x}}} \ell_{+1}(h(\tilde{\mathbf{x}}), z) + \lambda c(\mathbf{x}, \tilde{\mathbf{x}})
$$

where $\ell_{+1}$ is the loss function of the intermediary and $c$ is a cost function which characterises the cost incurred by the intermediary for changing $\mathbf{x}$ to $\tilde{\mathbf{x}}$.

Meanwhile the learner wants to minimise their own risk with respect to the labels $y$ given that the intermediary will modify incoming input examples optimally:
$$
\arg\min_{h \in \mathcal{H}} \mathbb{E}[\ell_{-}(h(x^{\star}), y)]
$$
where $\ell_{-}$ is the loss function of the learner. Now assume that $\mathcal{H}$ is the class of linear predictors, $\ell_{-}$ and $\ell_{+}$ are the square loss, and that $c(x, \tilde{x}) = \|x - \tilde{x}\|_{1}$. Then it can be shown that

$$
\mathbf{x}^{\star} = 
\begin{cases}
\mathbf{x} & \text{if } \mathbf{w} = 0 \text{ or } \|\mathbf{w}\|_{\infty}|z - \mathbf{w}^{\top}\mathbf{x}| \leq \gamma/2 \\
\mathbf{x} + \|\mathbf{w}\|_{\infty}(z - \mathbf{w}^{\top}\mathbf{x}) - \frac{\gamma}{2\|\mathbf{w}\|_{\infty}} & \text{if } \|\mathbf{w}\|_{\infty}(z - \mathbf{w}^{\top}\mathbf{x}) > \gamma/2\\
\mathbf{x} + \|\mathbf{w}\|_{\infty}(z - \mathbf{w}^{\top}\mathbf{x}) + \frac{\gamma}{2\|\mathbf{w}\|_{\infty}} & \text{if } \|\mathbf{w}\|_{\infty}(z - \mathbf{w}^{\top}\mathbf{x}) < \gamma /2
\end{cases}
$$

Thus given a sample $(x, y, z)$, the actual prediction made by $\mathbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ after modification is:

$$
h_{\mathbf{w}}(\mathbf{x}, z) = 
\begin{cases}
\mathbf{w}^{\top}\mathbf{x} & \text{if } \mathbf{w} = 0 \text{ or } \|\mathbf{w}\|_{\infty}|z_{i} - \mathbf{w}^{\top}\mathbf{x}| \leq \gamma/2 \\
z - \frac{\gamma}{2\|\mathbf{w}\|_{\infty}} & \text{if } \|\mathbf{w}\|_{\infty}(z - \mathbf{w}^{\top}\mathbf{x}) > \gamma/2\\
z + \frac{\gamma}{2\|\mathbf{w}\|_{\infty}} & \text{if } \|\mathbf{w}\|_{\infty}(z - \mathbf{w}^{\top}\mathbf{x}) < -\gamma/2
\end{cases}
$$

In other words, minimising the risk is equivalent to minimising the risk in a standard risk minimisation problem in which hypothesis are piecewise linear functions on $(\mathbf{x}, z)$ with three components.

Now assume that I have a training dataset $S = \{(x_{i}, y_{i}, z_{i})\}^{m}_{i=1]}$ of uncorrupted data points (for example, maybe I got these by going through some verification process). Then I can perform empirical risk minimisation:
$$
\arg\min_{h_{\mathbf{w}}} \sum_{i=1}^{m}\ell_{-1}(h_{\mathbf{w}}(\mathbf{x}_{i}, z_{i}), y_{i})
$$

I want to know two things about this ERM procedure:

1. Is this optimisation tractable?
2. Does the resulting hypothesis found generalise well?

For question 2, note that $h_{\mathbf{w}}$ is a piecewise linear function, therefore if the hypothesis class of piecewise continuous linear functions with a fixed number of components has bounded complexity, then one would get generalisation guarantees for the ERM procedure above.

This is a rather brute force approach, which avoids specific details regarding the functions being optimised over, but may be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will address the "VC" part. Let $F_{d,k}$ be the collection of all $k$-piecewise linear functions from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Let
$H_{d,k}=\mathrm{sign}(F_{d,k})$ be this class thresholded at zero
$$
H_{d,k}=\{h=\mathrm{sign}(f) : f\in F_{d,k}\}.
$$
I claim that each $h\in H_{d,k}$ can be computed by a Boolean circuit realized by a directed acyclic graph with $k$ internal nodes, where each node is labeled with an element of $H_{d,1}$. This is described in detail in the Kearns-Vazirani book, Section 3.7
https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-computational-learning-theory
; here is the accompanying figure:

[image]

Theorem 3.6 therein states that $\mathrm{VC}(H_{d,k})\le 2k\log(ek)\mathrm{VC}(H_{d,1})$. Since $\mathrm{VC}(H_{d,1})=d+1$, this yields an estimate of
$O(kd\log k)$ -- worse by a factor of $\log k$ than yours. Intuitively, one might imagine that this $\log k$ factor accounts for the fact that the break points are not fixed.

As for the fat-shattering dimension of $F_{d,k}$, that is indeed an excellent question, one that I shall have to think about.

Comment: Very interesting! I guess the issue of generalising the proof to fat shattering dimension is that two states are no longer enough, as you need a state for points that lie in the margin $\gamma$.

Comment: I can express a $k$-piecewise linear function as a min-max circuit (i.e., a layered DAG as in the figure) where each "gate" is either a min or a max, and the internal nodes are linear functions. But there is no analogous fat-dim result. The max-only case was non-trivial enough -- I devoted a whole paper to it!
https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.04763

If this is sufficiently interesting, I'll be happy to work on it. Is it?

Comment: I have updated the question with some discussion as to its motivation.

Comment: Interesting, thanks!